# Remove all tabstops for a particular page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to format a Word document with the help of VBA.

If I supply a page number, it should clear all tabstops for that particular page only.

I have the code to clear all the tabstops but could not modify it for a specific page.

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.TabStops.ClearAll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim pnum As Integer
pnum = InputBox("Enter page number")
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(pnum).Rectangles(1).Range.Paragraphs.TabStops.ClearAll
```

Remember that pages are a fairly arbitrary concept in a document, so it might not be so easy to identify the content you want to by a page number. Elements that span multiple pages (like tables) can also cause confusion.